# How do I fix loc error when subsetting by row content with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I'm trying to subset a dataframe by the contents of a specific column, but for some reason it's not working, no matter what I try to do. The pandas website suggested way of doing this would go as follows with my data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('D:/vini_/Vini/Estudos/FEA.Dev/Cases/case_avancado/Vendas.csv')
>>> data.head(5)
```

```
DataVenda     ...       Continente 
0     6/1/2017  ...            Europa
1     6/1/2017  ...  América do Norte
2     6/1/2017  ...    América do Sul
3     6/1/2017  ...            Europa
4     6/1/2017  ...  América do Norte
```

```
>>> data[data['Continente'] == 'Europa']
```

But this last line of code throws up an error:

```
data[data['Continente'] == 'Europa']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\...\base.py", line 2895, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Continente'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-474c815ad299>", line 1, in <module>
    data[data['Continentes'] == 'Europa']

  File "C:\...\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\...\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'Continente'
```

If it helps, here's a list of the column types from the dataframe:

```
DataVenda            object
Produto              object
Subcategoria         object
PrecoUnitario       float64
CustoUnitario       float64
Marca                object
QtdVendida            int64
Faturamento         float64
NomeCliente          object
Sobrenome            object
Pais                 object
Continente           object
dtype: object
```

Does anyone knows how if it's a python error or if I'm doing it the wrong way?

Comment: The actual column is `"Continente"`, not `"Continentes"`. Change it and it should be fine

Comment: Seems like there isn't any column named `Continentes` which is being called. Seems like column name is `Continente`.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError: 'Continentes'` means that your table does not have a column labeled "`Continentes`"

I think that you want to delete the letter "`s`" from the end of "`Continentes`"

There is a column of the table named "`Continente`."
However, there is no column named "`Continentes`"

---

`Error de claves: 'Continentes'` significa que su tabla no tiene una columna etiquetada" `Continentes`"

Creo que quieres borrar la letra " `s` "del final de" `Continentes`"

Hay una columna de la tabla llamada "`Continente`".
Sin embargo, no hay una columna llamada " `Continentes`"

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo on the question, I'm using ```Continente``` on my code, but it gives the same error. It's like the column names are not even there

Comment: Update: I found the error, the author of the dataset put 2 to 3 random (blank) spaces after each column name. So I the name is actually ```Continente ``` not ```Continente```.

Comment: @vini_serpa In Python, you should always use the `strip()` function to remove leading and trailing white-space characters from strings. For example, `txt = txt.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the column names had spacing after them and, for some reason, python recongnizes it as valid characters. After changing `Continente` for `Continente` , everything worked.
In conclusion, use the names given by the `data.columns` function, not the ones you see onscreen.

Comment: You say that `data.columns` is a function, but it is not actually a function. If  `data.columns` were a function, you would use parentheses with it. You would type `data.columns()` instead of `data.columns`.  `data.columns` is known as a "class ***attribute***" or "***member variable***" of the pandas.DataFrame class.